# how to add dependencies to gradle / faas / visual studio code / java8

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I don't know how much time I lost on it. I can't add to the simple faas function any jar.

```
faas-cli new --lang java8 test --prefix="domain"
faas-cli build -f tes.tyml
```

Great! - I have new simple and clean solution with java

then i opening build.gradle changes two lines: (adding one implementation and change repository to meaven)

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
     api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
     implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports.jasperreports:6.10.0'
     implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile project(':model')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral {}
}

faas-cli build -f test.yml ./web-proxy/build.gradle
```

and then BOOM

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':function:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':function:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find net.sf.jasperreports.jasperreports:6.10.0:.
     Required by:
         project :function
```

I can't add any jar to the faas java8 project for 4 hours! please help
nowadays i'm development .net and here i was supposed to do a small quick function with jasper and that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the Jasper reports dependency (the separation character between the Maven group ID and the artifact ID should be a colon, but you have a dot). Try with this:

`implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.10.0'`

Comment: // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1/com.lowagie.text
compile group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1', name: 'com.lowagie.text', version: '2.1.7'
any idea, cant add this jar too

Comment: thanks for help, i know its a new question but in the same context.

I cant add 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1/com.lowagie.text' to dependensie to gradle at faas-cli java8 template

Comment: is there a change to add statick file jar? cant find solution too

Comment: You should just be able to copy/paste the dependency as it is stated in mvnrepository.com as long as it is in MavenCentral (which it is). You could try changing "compile" to "implementation", which is the new way to do it, but I don't see why it wouldn't work to begin with.

Comment: I can't find a pattern but I have found the trial and error method
`implementation 'com.lowagie: itext: 2.1.7'`

Comment: generally its very confusing in maven i can see:
`implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'org.springframework.beans', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'` but work this `implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'`

Comment: generally I added all necessary jars - thanks for help!